# Google Maps API v3 MouseEvent return position of marker not mouse

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have implemented a map with markers and listeners on the markers.

```
...
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'rightclick',function(event) {showRightClick(event, map, marker);});
...

// Show Right Click Menu
function showRightClick(event, map, marker) {
        var point = map.getCanvasProjection().fromLatLngToContainerPixel(event.latLng);
        var scriptInterface = getHeader();
        var screenX = point.x + window.screenLeft;
        var screenY = point.y + window.screenTop;
        scriptInterface.rightClick(marker.name, marker.objectid, marker.dimobjectid, screenX, screenY);
}
```

But, when the listener triggers, the event latitude and longitude is that of the marker and not the mouse.  So, the right click menu I am trying to show appears at the bottom of the marker and not the mouse position.

Does anyone know if this is a bug or expected behaviour?

Comment: wouldn't it just be easier to display your menu based on an absolute position of the mouse relative to the page and totally ignore the map (with the exception of your marker object)? Also.. the right click for the MAP is the position of the mouse.. any event on the marker will always be the marker's position.

Answer (score 0):

Although the documentation says that the `MouseEvent` event's `LatLng` is "The latitude/longitude that was below the cursor when the event occurred," it was the location of the marker in Version 2.

The behaviour may be expected to be the same in Version 3. I don't believe it's a bug, although I can see it produces unexpected results for right-click.

You may need to use a DOM right-click event instead (although then it will be difficult if not impossible to associate that with a marker).

Comment: In my previous version using the V2 API, the listener was on the map object rather than the marker object.  When the rightclick was caught it passed the overlay in the event if the right click was performed over the marker.  This then meant the point provided was that of the mouse rather than the marker.  But, this does not appear to work in V3 and the right click is not available if the listener is on the map.